# How to list shortcuts by source in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When a shortcut's keybinding is changed, its source changes from `Default` to `User`. Is there a way to list only the shortcuts with source = User?

Comment: Well, all the User-defined shortcuts are in your keybindings.json file so that is a list - that file also includes shortcuts you have deleted.  You can search for "User" and it will actually search for that in your keyboard shortcuts.  That will find all the source=user shortcuts but also three non-user shortcuts because they have "user" I them (like "Open user settings") so that isn't too bad.  I don't see a way to print that list though (other than a screen clip).

Comment: You're right, keybindings.json does have user sourced shortcuts and I guess this should be enough for me for now. Also, I should say there is no match found when I search "User".

Comment: That's odd - when I search for user: Gear icon/Keyboard shortcuts/ and then user in the search area I get all my user-defined shortcuts and only three default shortcuts.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102692/can-i-see-and-individually-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-sublime-text-keym/61526583#61526583 for a way to filter `user`-defined shortcuts that may be in v1.45.